# Consuming Twitter stream with tweepy and serving content via websocket with gevent

Tags: python, twitter, gevent, tweepy

my goal is be able to send the stream readed in twitter with tweepy and serving the content using websocket with gevent.
I had  solved the two parts of the problem in two simple scripts obtained in the official documentation.

1)In one side the I can read the Twiter stream using the tweepy:

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import json

access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""

class myStreamListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        decoded = json.loads(data)
        if decoded["coordinates"] is not None:
            print decoded["coordinates"]["coordinates"]
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

if __name__ == '__main__':

    l = myStreamListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)

    geobox_world = [-180,-90,180,90]
    stream.filter(locations=geobox_world)
```

This print me in the standard output the information required

2) On the other side I took a  dump example of gevent in order to be able of make a 'thread' capable of serving the data to a web client

```
from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler
from gevent import pywsgi
import gevent
import time

def app(environ, start_response):
    ws = environ['wsgi.websocket']
    contador = 0
    while True:
        strTemp = "hola" + str(contador) 
        ws.send( strTemp )
        time.sleep(1)
        contador = contador + 1

server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(('', 10000), app, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

The problem that I faced on is the join of two codes;I not be able of make run myStreamListener inside of a  tweepy 'thread'

How i can do this? One approach maybe could be make a middle buffer but this is out off my pythons skills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The StreamListener runs on a gevent greenlet, and sends to all the websockets connected to the server the parsed coordinates.

Tested with [iocat](https://github.com/moul/iocat) localhost:10000

```py
import gevent
import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_all()

from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler
from gevent import pywsgi

from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import json

access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""


class MyStreamListener(StreamListener):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sockets = []
        auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
        self.stream = Stream(auth, self)

    def add_socket(self, ws):
        self.sockets.append(ws)

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.stream.filter(track="#linux")
        except Exception:
            self.stream.disconnect()

    def start(self):
        gevent.spawn(self.run)

    def send(self, ws, coordinates):
        try:
            ws.send(json.dumps(coordinates))
        except Exception:
            # the web socket die..
            self.sockets.remove(ws)

    def on_data(self, data):
        decoded = json.loads(data)
        if decoded.get("coordinates", None) is not None:
            coordinates = decoded["coordinates"]["coordinates"]
            for ws in self.sockets:
                gevent.spawn(self.send, ws, coordinates)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print "Error", status

    def on_timeout(self):
        print "tweepy timeout.. wait 30 seconds"
        gevent.sleep(30)

stream_listener = MyStreamListener()
stream_listener.start()


def app(environ, start_response):
    ws = environ['wsgi.websocket']
    stream_listener.add_socket(ws)
    while not ws.closed:
        gevent.sleep(0.1)

server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(('', 10000), app, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```